# Combinação de função javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, possuo duas funções que funcionam separadamente muito bom, porém preciso combinar elas agora para uma organizar o resultado da outra.
**Função de Orgãos:**

```
$scope.$watch('organ_id', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != null && newValue != '') {
       $scope.servicesPromise =
          $http
            .get('/api/services.json?organ_id=' + newValue)
              .success(function (data) {
                $scope.total_pages = data.total_pages;
                $scope.services = data.services;
            });
        };
    }, true);
```

**Função por letras**

```
$scope.byLetter = function (letter) {
      $scope.servicesPromise =
          $http
            .get('/api/services.json?letter=' + letter)
              .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.total_pages = data.total_pages;
                    $scope.services = data.services;
            $scope.tama_letra = data.tam_letter;
                });
    };
```

A função de órgãos trás um conjunto e o que desejo é que quando eu selecionar a ordem por letras o retorno seja somente os serviços daquele dado orgão com aquela letra.

por exemplo:
Se escolhi orgão X;
tenho como retorno SX serviços;
neste conjunto eu quero saber quais serviços que inicial com a letra E;
Escolho a letra E;
preciso que a resposta, neste caso sejam os SX que iniciam com E.

Comment: O seu serviço aceita os dois parâmetros combinados?

Comment: Sim, a função aceita!

Comment: Então não seria só fazer uma chamada com os dois parâmetros?

Comment: Justo, na combinação que imagino, os parâmetros seriam (organ_id, letter).

Comment: Beleza, vou escrever uma resposta baseado nisso então

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer a requisição com dois parâmetros:

```
function _search(organ_id, letter) {
  var params = {};

  params.organ_id = organ_id;
  params.letter = letter;

  return $http.get('/api/services.json', {params: params}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.total_pages = data.total_pages;
    $scope.services = data.services;
  });
}
```

Comment: Show, cara valeu mesmo!